# sed: Delete first line of hold space?

Tags: sed

How do I delete the first line of the hold space in sed?

I've tried

```
x;
s/.*\n//;
x;
```

But `.*\n` matches up to the last newline, deleting all the lines except for the last one.

Comment: Could you tell why you keep it in hold space if you want to delete it later? It may help for finding the best solution.

Comment: Any time you use the term "hold space" you are using the wrong tool since sed is only for simple substitutions on individual lines and all of it's constructs except s, g, and p (with -n) became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented. Post some sample input and expected output and add an awk tag if you'd like help.

Answer (score 3):

this should remove the 1st line from "hold space"

```
x;s/[^\n]*\n//
```

Example:

```
kent$  sed -n 'H;${x;p}' <(seq 3)      

1
2
3
```

remove the first empty line:

```
kent$  sed -n 'H;${x;s/[^\n]*\n//;p}' <(seq 3) 
1
2
3
```

Comment: `$ sed -n 'H;${x;s/[^\n]*\n//;p;}' <(seq 3)` gave `3`. I think it interpreted `[^\n]` as "don't match ``\`` or `n`". Any way to circumvent this?

Comment: @EpicOrange Sed should interpret `\n` as a single newline character. But what do you want to accomplish with getting rid of a single line? Perhaps you need to read the file into hold (if it will fit) then simply search replace the line you want to get rid of and swap it back out.

Comment: In the above example, as only the `H` command has been employed, it would be safe to remove the first character (`s/.//`) to achieve the same result. To remove the first line in hold space/pattern space then it is a question of removing zero or more non-newlines followed by a newline as stated (`s/^[^\n]*\n//`).

Comment: @A.Danischewski no, SOME seds will interpret `\n` as a newline character. That behavior is undefined by POSIX. All POSIX seds will recognize a backslash followed by a literal newline as a newline character. This is simply not a job for sed anyway though so it's academic.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm not sure about "undefined by POSIX". [It says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02) `The escape sequence '\n' shall match a <newline> embedded in the pattern space. A literal <newline> shall not be used in the BRE of a context address or in the substitute function.` [The revision from 2008](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02) says the same.

Comment: Yeah looks like they've defined that now for sed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple put any random string with `h` i.e `1h;1d`, by default it's empty.